# Kotlin + Mongock for Spring Boot + Spring Data: IllegalAccessError

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mongock

I have created a Kotlin application that connects to a MongoDB on Atlas to fetch some data via Spring Data JPA. For future changes to the document structure, I have experimented with Mongock. I have gone for the simplest possible integration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongock
class MyKotlinApplication
...
```

and declared in the `application.properties`

```
# mongock
mongock.migration-scan-package=org.foo.bar.changelogs
mongock.runner-type=applicationrunner
```

And created a `@ChangeUnit`. Mongock finds it and tries to execute it...

```
package org.foo.bar.changelogs

import io.mongock.api.annotations.ChangeUnit
import io.mongock.api.annotations.Execution
import io.mongock.api.annotations.RollbackExecution
import org.foo.bar.units.Unit
import org.foo.bar.units.UnitRepository

@ChangeUnit(id = "AddDispatchedBy2", order = "2", author = "Patrick")
class AddDispatchedBy2 {

    @Execution
    fun execute(unitRepository: UnitRepository) {

        val units = unitRepository.findAll().toList();
        for (it in units) {
            it.dispatchedBy = "unknown"
        }
        units.forEach { unitRepository.save(it) }

    }

    @RollbackExecution
    fun executeRollback() {

        System.out.println("oops");

    }
}
```

..but it fails:
`Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.foo.bar.units.UnitRepository_$$_mongock_21d_0.toString()`

The `UnitRepository` is nothing special either:

```
@Repository
interface UnitRepository : CrudRepository<Unit, String>
```

I have understood from [the docs](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/runner/springboot/index.html) that the application context is available because the runner takes care of that, and that Mongock somehow proxies the beans. But that doesn't seem to work...?

I have tried to declare the dependency to the `UnitRepository` in the constructor of the `@ChangeUnit` but the problem remains. Most blog articles and search hits on github show the usage of `MongoTemplate` but I still hope that I'd be able to use my own Repository bean.

Comment: Please [edit] your post title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of the tags followed by the single word *illegalaccesserror*. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning about the question content to a future site user skimming a list of search results. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems related to the proxy Mongock uses. It's probably something to do with the JVM version.

If you annotate the parameter `unitRepository` with `@NonLockGuarded`, it will be probably fix it.